# Cyrillic / Russian filenames - 404 not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to upload some russian filenames e.g. автомобилей.php however they end up in a 404 error.

I've tried to specify the charset in Filezilla while uploading the files to cp-1251, windows-1251, cp1251 but I am still getting a

Not Found

The requested URL /Ð°Ð²Ñ‚Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾ was not found on this server.

Any ideas on how I can have this resolved? Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your encoding (cp-1251) is single byte ASCII+Cyrillic, while the `Ð°Ð²Ñ‚Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾` hints that the text was created in UTF-8 (6 multibyte characters, most likely). Using anything other than ASCII or maybe Latin-1 encoding for a filename is usually going to be asking for trouble, although if you have a Cyrillic-specific operating system and Cyrillic-aware utiities, you might get away with it. Just be aware of whether you need CP-1251 or UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score -2):

Convert them in latin script symbols. This is the best and the easiest way.

It's generally a bad practice to use non latin script file names in the web. But it is possible to [make urls in Cyrillic](http://rapidup.ru/otvety/7.html).